# is there a way to use an event object inside a second function? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, events

I am trying to combine two functions together which are pretty much totally similar and the only difference is one uses `focusout` and one uses `keypress` with the event object to check if the keypress is a enter key.

But somehow I couldn't get it to work, is there a possible way for what I am doing with my codes?

```
function q1Inputs(selector, action){
  selector.on(action, function(e){
     var value = $(this).val();
     var closestBetQs = $(this).closest('.bet-qs');
     var errorMsg = closestBetQs.find('.err-msg');

     if(action == 'keypress'){
        if(e.which == 13){
           q1Outputs(value, closestBetQs, errorMsg);
        }
     }

     if(action == 'focusout'){
        q1Outputs(value, closestBetQs, errorMsg);
     }
  });
```

}

```
 q1Inputs($('.q1 ~ input'), 'focusout');
 q1Inputs($('.q1 ~ input'), 'keypress');
```

Comment: No need to pass `action`, just refer to `e.type` to get the event type.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qLvsjofa/